# Class Resolving in one namespace, but not the other

Tags: scala, playframework, classpath

When running `play compile`, I get a compile-time error.

```
[error] test.scala:14: object BOMInputStream is not a member of package org.ap
ache.commons.io.input
[error] import org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream
[error]        ^
[error] test.scala:80: not found: type BOMInputStream
[error]     val bomIn = new BOMInputStream(fileInpStream, false)
[error]                     ^
[error] two errors found
```

However, I successfully ran a `scalatest` test using the BOMInputStream in the same `play` project within the `/test` directory.

When I comment out the offending lines in the above compile-time error, the test succeeds.

Note that I've updated my `/project/Build.scala` appropriately:

`"org.apache.commons"        % "commons-io"      % "1.3.2"`

Comment: Did you put the dependency at the correct place in Build.scala? Didn't you put it only to test classpath?

Comment: I believe so. I added it to `val appDependencies = Seq( ... )`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After deleting a JAR, which contained the `BOMInputStream` class, from my `PLAY-PROJECT/lib/` directory, I was able to compile.